How to sync entire repository in Azure devops using yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo1
      type: git
      name: projectname/repo1
    - repository: repo2
      type: git
      name: projectname/repo2

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: repo2
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "change directory"
  inputs:
    script: |
       cd repo2

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git config --global user.email "xxxx"
      git config --global user.name "xxxx"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "pull"
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 pull origin development

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/Pipelines/'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/Pipelines/'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 checkout development

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 add --all

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 commit -m "Azure Pipeline Repository Integration"

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 status

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 push -u origin development    

In the above code I'm just trying to copy only pipelines folder from repo1 to repo2. But i want sync all the folders in repo1 to repo2. How to do that


In the above code I'm just trying to copy only pipelines folder from repo1 to repo2. But i want sync all the folders in repo1 to repo2. How to do that

To sync all the folders in repo1 to repo2, you need to keep .git files in repo2 on agent, but replace all other files. Remove your CopyFiles@2 task, add below two tasks:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: clean repo except git
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/' -Recurse |
      Where-Object { !$_.FullName.Contains(".git") } |
      Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/'
    Contents: |
      **/*
      !.git/**/*
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/'
    #CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

The powershell task above remove the files except .git, and CopyFiles@2 will sync all files except .git.
In addition, you should add - checkout: repo1 ahead.
On pipeline repo, use Collection scoped build service account:

On projectname where has repo1, repo2, make sure the build service account has contribut and force push permission, so that it can sync the code.

The whole yaml as below:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo1
      type: git
      name: wadetest14/repo1
    - repository: repo2
      type: git
      name: wadetest14/repo2

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: repo1
- checkout: repo2
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "change directory"
  inputs:
    script: |
       cd repo2

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git config --global user.email "wadetest"
      git config --global user.name "wadetest@hotmail.com"

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "pull"
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 pull origin development

# - task: CopyFiles@2
#   inputs:
#     SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/Pipelines/'
#     Contents: '**'
#     TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/Pipelines/'
#     CleanTargetFolder: true
#     OverWrite: true

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: clean repo except git
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/' -Recurse |
      Where-Object { !$_.FullName.Contains(".git") } |
      Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/'
    Contents: |
      **/*
      !.git/**/*
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/'
    #CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 checkout development

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 add --all

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 commit -m "Azure Pipeline Repository Integration"

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 status

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      git -C repo2 push -u origin development    


Edit：

i need to ignore i file from syncing how can i achieve that. for example a file called a.txt how can i ignore that file from syncing

Same as .git files, you can add one more exclusion in powershell and copyfile task to ingore the a.txt.
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: clean repo except git
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/' -Recurse |
      Where-Object { (!$_.FullName.Contains(".git")) -and (!$_.FullName.Contains("a.txt")) } |
      Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/'
    Contents: |
      **/*
      !.git/**/*
      !**/a.txt
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/'
    #CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

Add more:

Can i ignore first 250lines in that file and can i sync other 250lines from repo1

As mentioned above, you can add one more exclusion in powershell and copy file task to igore the a.txt file. Then add one more task to replace the content, ignore the first 250 lines.
I tested for less string, please replace 3 to 250, my a.txt is under repo1, repo2.
- powershell: |
    $sourcecontent = Get-Content -Path "repo1/a.txt"
    $targetcontent = Get-Content -Path "repo2/a.txt"

    # Modify the desired lines (starting from line 4)
    if ($sourcecontent.Length -lt $targetcontent.Length) {
      for ($i = 3; $i -lt $sourcecontent.Length; $i++) {
        $targetcontent[$i] = $sourcecontent[$i]
      }
    }
    else {
      for ($i = 3; $i -lt $targetcontent.Length; $i++) {
        $targetcontent[$i] = $sourcecontent[$i]
      }
      for ($i = $targetcontent.Length; $i -lt $sourcecontent.Length; $i++ ) {
        $targetcontent += $sourcecontent[$i]
      }
    }

    # Write the updated content back to the text file
    ($targetcontent)[0..($sourcecontent.Length-1)] | Set-Content -Path "repo2/a.txt"

Content replaced:


Hi @wade zhou,i appreciate your effort but when i tried your code when i execute it the contents (files & folders) in repo 2 are getting deleted. It is working as a mirror task. I don't want to delete my contents in repo2. Also i want to ignore certain files(ex. a.txt) to sync from repo1 to repo2

I have updated your code,

task: PowerShell@2
displayName: clean repo except git
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/' -Recurse |
Where-Object { !$_.FullName.Contains(".git") }
By using this code the contents in repo2 won't get deleted


@Vinay.Mvinu.M, there is Remove-Item -Recurse -Force at the end in the task(use | before), please copy the completed task for a check, let me know if you have any queries.

zhou, i need to ignore i file from syncing how can i achieve that.
for example a file called a.txt how can i ignore that file from syncing

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, you can add one more exclusion in both powershell and copyfile task, i will edit the reply with sample, please check.

Thank you @wade Zhou, i have another doubt as i said earlier i have file called a.txt which has a contents of around 500lines. Can i ignore first 250lines in that file and can i sync other 250lines from repo1. Is it possible to that. If it is possible how can we do that?

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, it's possible, you can add a new task after copyfile task to paritically override the a.txt content, and then upload to remote. But it's a new query for file content replacement, it's recommended to raise a new ticket for the tracking, thanks.

You are welcome! I did some investigation to replace content in a.txt, ignore first 250 lines. As mentioned above, you need to add a new task after copy file task, with a script to replace string one by one. I will edit the reply with details, please check.

BTW, it's recommended to achieve the replacement on local machine, than you can migrate to DevOps.  DevOps is used for CICD purpose only.

Thank you @wade zhou, i will be waiting for your reply

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, please check my reply with add more content.

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, there's no built-in task to partically replace the content in the file, so we need an extra script task to do this, add the task after CopyFiles@2 task. Let me know if it works for you.

Hi @wade zhou, the ignore task is not working

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, what's the detail of not working? Is the txt not replaced? You can create 2 a.txt following the structure, and have a check the content after the task. Or do you have other stuff not mentioned?

The code is getting replaced from 1st line. below code works if i set overwrite to false in copy task. But if set to false it wont replace the other files contents.

powershell: |
$sourceFile = "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo1/Sample_B/sample_b.txt"
$targetFile = "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repo2/Sample_B/sample_b.txt"
$contentToAppend = Get-Content $sourceFile
$targetContent = Get-Content $targetFile
$targetContent[0..10] + $contentToAppend | Set-Content $targetFile
displayName: 'Copy from 10th line of sample_b.txt'


so can you give condition for that overwrite. For sample_b.txt file overwrite should be set to false. For other files it should be true

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, it appears you didn't follow the steps above. If you exclude the txt file from clean repo except git powershell task, and then exclude again (!**/sample_b.txt) in copyfile task, you can use overwrite as true, actually txt file is not touched yet in repo2. In the next powershell script(the add more task), it replaced the txt file content. Please use the same code as shown above to replace the content. If you would like to copy from 10th, change 3 to 10, don't change the script to yours.

hi @wade zhou i have added everything , still the .contents are getting pasted from 1st line

@Vinay.Mvinu.M, can you edit the ticket, add your current pipeline yaml, so i can have a check?
